# Why is my query not working while I tested in query helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, using

```
protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   try {
      string turusec = ASPxComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

      switch (turusec)
      {
         case "Laptop":
            SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO Laptops(L_marka_ismi,L_marka_modeli,L_marka_quantity, L_marka_fiyati,L_marka_discount, L_marka_description, )" +
                    "VALUES('" + ASPxTextBox1.Text + "','" + ASPxTextBox2.Text + "','" + ASPxTextBox3.Text + "','" + ASPxTextBox4.Text + "','" + ASPxTextBox5.Text + "','" + ASPxMemo1.Text + "'))";
          break;
```

Comment: What error or exception did you have?

Comment: What value is `turusec` holding? Where is `SqlDataSource1` instantiated?

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times by the way..

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra ',' (comma) at the end of the fields list (before `VALUES`):

```
INSERT INTO Laptops(L_marka_ismi,L_marka_modeli,L_marka_quantity, 
L_marka_fiyati,L_marka_discount, L_marka_description**,**) VALUES...
```

Comment: i edited comma but stil not saving in database :( i will send you full codes

Comment: Your SQL statement also ends with an extra ')'

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace www._3SAC.com.Administrator
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }

Comment: @user2179209 edit your question and add source code there, instead of in comments. This helps other users to see the full context, instead of having to sift through comments to get the whole picture.